# Query updating only one row instead of all

Tags: mysql

Query explanation: there are two tables, Invoice, and temp. I need to take zip codes from temp table and push them to the Invoice table, based on the invoice number.

Query:

```
UPDATE 
Invoice
SET 
Invoice.zip_code = (SELECT zip_code FROM temp WHERE Invoice.invoice_number = temp.invoice_number)
WHERE 
Invoice.invoice_date >= '2017-08-01';
```

my temp table has 3 invoices in it
[image]
after running the query, only invoice 693459 is updated
[image]

Comment: I mean only invoice 272739 is updated.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It doesn't look like fiddle lets me use UPDATE queries, only SELECT.

Comment: Updates go in the first window. I don't know if it accepts selects inside updates, but don't let that stop you from providing the DDLs

Answer (score 0):

Your query will not do the job -because it is not addressing all records but is applied just once to the first record.

```
UPDATE Invoice SET zip_code=Temp.zipcode
FROM Invoice INNER JOIN Temp ON
Invoice.invoice_number=Temp.invoice_number
WHERE invoice_date>='2017-08-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that invoice_date in the `datetime` format within your table.

```
WHERE DATE(Invoice.invoice_date) >= '2017-08-01';
```

Comment: For whatever reason it only matches against the first row in the temp table. I tried swapping rows 1 and 2, and as expected now I have two invoices with updated zips. I don't understand why it stops after the first match.